# Customer group price not showing in product list and view pages but showing in cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, product-view, group-price

I assigned customer group to a customer and added price to that group for a product the price not showing in list and view pages but in cart it is showing, the price is less to regular price.

Comment: Well this is completely depend on your theme

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala The thing is it shown until yesterday and stopped showing from this morning, can you help me with code to show group price `echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product);` is what it is actually

Comment: this code mean call `app/design/frontend/yourPackage/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/price.phtml` if you have not change layout file

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala can you please be clear